# Let the client to download a file from the server

Tags: php, file-io

I need to implement a code where I can let the client to download one or more local files on the web server.

I have 3 files: **file1.php**, **file2.js**, **file3.php** with the following codes.

In **file1.php**:

```
<select name="file_list" class="myclass" id="f_list" style="height:25px; width: 280px">

<?php
  foreach (new DirectoryIterator("$filesFolder") as $file)
  {
    if((htmlentities($file) !== ".") && (htmlentities($file) !== ".."))
    {
      echo "<option>" . htmlentities($file) . "</option>";
    }
  }
  ?>
  </select>

  <?php
  echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\" Download \" onClick=\"downloadFile()\"/>";
  ?>
```

in **file2.js**

```
function downloadFile()
{
  $("#activity").html("<img src=\"img.gif\" style=\"left: 590px;top: 74px;margin: auto;position: absolute;width: 32px;height: 32px;\" />");

    $("#content").load("file3.php",
    {
      filename: $("#f_list").val()
    });
}
```

**file3.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["filename"]))
{
  $filename = $_POST["filename"];
  /* testing string */
  echo $filesFolder.$filename;

  if(file_exists($filesFolder.$filename))
  {
    ob_start();
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filesFolder.$filename));
    readfile($filesFolder.$filename);
    ob_end_flush();
    exit;
  }
}
```

I took this last PHP code from the [readfile function PHP manual](http://php.net//manual/es/function.readfile.php) because the behaviour is exactly what I need. But when **file3.php** is executed, the content of the file (which is binary data) is printed out on the screen.

I think I am missing to implement some feature but I don't know what it could be.
How can I obtain the same result of the readfile PHP manual page?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try running it without the `echo()`?

Comment: You can only have 1 Content-Type per *content* unless dealing with multipart messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File2:**

You can't use `.load()` or similar methods to download a file.

Just use `window.location.href = "file3.php?filename="+$("#f_list").val();`

**File3:**

You can't output anything before calling `header()`s. Comment out `echo` on line 5.

In File 2 we are using GET instead of POST, replace `$_POST` with `$_GET`.

Comment: @simo-zz I'm glad that your problem is solved :) Please accept the answer which has helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

It might also help to not request the page using ajax, just use

```
window.location.href='/download/url';
```

If all headers are correct, it will open a download dialog without leaving the current page.

Comment: *"It might also help.."* - It is not possible to offer a download by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to try to open the file in a new tab/window:

```
function downloadFile()
{
    window.open("file3.php?filename=" + encodeURIComponent($("#f_list").val()));
}
```

Because the result of the PHP page has headers indicating that the content is a download not a page, the browser will not actually navigate, but will instead offer a download box.  Note that this method uses GET not POST, so you will have to change from `$_POST` to `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` in file3.php.  Also, make sure you remove your `echo` before the headers go out or this won't work.